# Verify my proof of $G$ is nilpotent iff $xy=yx \forall x,y\in G$ such that $(o(x),o(y))=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Prove: $G$ is nilpotent iff $xy=yx \forall x,y\in G$ such that $(o(x),o(y))=1$

$G$ is finite. Is that plausible?

**Attempt**:
Suppose $G$ is nilpotnet. Then $G=P_1\times\ldots\times P_k$ where $P_1,...,P_k$ are the normal Sylow-$P$ subgroups of $G$. Let $x$ and $y$ be two elements of $G$ such that $(o(x),o(y))=1$.
If one of them is $1$ then we are done.
Otherwise, both $x,y \ne 1$. Since the orders have no common divisor that is not 1, $x$ and $y$ are composed by completely different $P_i$'s.
For example: If $x=p_1\cdot p_5\cdot p_{20}$ where $\{p_j\in P_j|j\in \{1,2,\ldots,20\}, p_j\ne 0\}$ then for $y$ of the aforementioned form $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{20},\ldots,y_k)$, $y_1=y_2=\ldots=y_{20}=0$ necessarily.
Therefore $xy=x_1\cdot \ldots\cdot x_k \cdot y_1\ldots\cdot y_k$ where $x_i,y_i$ are either $0$ or in $P_i$ and if one is in $P_i$ the other one isn't. The reduced result of $x_1\cdot \ldots\cdot x_k \cdot y_1\ldots\cdot y_k$ will be a multiplication(or sum) of elements, each belong to a different $P_i$. Therefore they are commutative and we can get $xy=yx$.

Comment: yes it is finite..

Comment: I've taken the time to improve a bit of your MathJax. First of all it's advisable to use _as few MathJax-Blocks as possible_, for example `$x,y$` should be preferred to `$x$,$y$`. Secondly the commands `\ldots` and `\{` / `\}` produce $\ldots, \{, \}$ respectively. For more tips, visit [the help page](/help/notation), it links to a bunch of MathJax tutorial threads on meta :) Also, italics are produced in the question and comments via `_text_`: _text_. Using MathJax for markup is discouraged for multiple reasons, see meta for more information.

Comment: By the way, this result is true in infinite nilpotent groups provided that $o(x)$ and $o(y)$ are both finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is the correct one, but perhaps it'd be clearer as follows:

$$G=P_1\times\ldots\times P_k\;,\;\;P_i\;\;\text{the different Sylow subgroups of}\;\;G\;\implies$$

$$\forall\,g\in G\;\;\text{we can write uniquely}\;\;g=(x_1,...,x_n)\;,\;\;x_i\in P_i$$

and the operation is multiplication coordinatewise.

Now, if we have two elements with coprime orders

$$x=(x_1,..,x_k)\;,\;\;y=(y_1,..,y_k)\;,\;\;g.c.d(o(x)\,,\,o(y))=1$$

then **it must be** that for all $\;1\le i\le k\;$, either $\;x_i=1\;$ or $\;y_i=1\;$ (*why*?), and then the claim follows at once from the fact that

$$\forall\,i=1,2,...,k\;,\;\;\;[x_i,y_i]=1\implies [x,y]=1$$

and we're done.

Comment: That's what I said... I called it "0" instead of "1" which was wrong I suppose...Thank you for this practical system.

Comment: And that's why I said your idea is the correct one. Whether my way of presenting the proof is clearer than yours or not is a matter of taste. :)

Comment: Yes, yours is better yo use. 
I should make myself clearer and formal.

Comment: How is it proved the other way? 
Completely differently?

Comment: @Meitar I think so: let $\;P_i\;$ be some Sylow subgroup of $\;G\;$ for each prime divisor of its order, and look at the subgroup $\;H:=\langle\,P_1,\ldots,P_k\,\rangle\;$ . Clearly, $|H|=|G|\implies G=H\;$ , and now, for each $\;i\;$ and for each $\;g\in G\;,\;\;P_i^g=g^{-1}P_ig=P_i\;$ (why? This is the gist of the proof), and thus $\;\forall\, i\;,\;\;P_i\lhd G\;$ and we're done.